# How do I register a custom IHttpModule with HttpServer

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpmodule

I am using the HttpServer class to test my web api.  In my application, I have a custom IHttpModule that handles some URL rewriting.  I need this module to process the requests for my web api as well.  Here is my code that I use to create the HttpServer object.

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(ServerUrl);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(config.Routes);
FilterConfig.RegisterWebApiFilters(config.Filters);
var httpServer = new HttpServer(config);
```

Can someone tell me the obvious thing I am missing that I need to do to register my module with the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use HttpModules with a self hosted WebAPI server. I think what you need is a MessageHandler.

- [Http Message Handlers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers)
- [DelegatingHandler (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx)

Comment: Took me a while, but I finally figured out how to refactor my code to use a message handler.